# Python tqdm package - how to configure for less frequent status bar updates

Tags: python, loops, pycharm, statusbar, tqdm

I'm using a `tqdm` package (v4.19.5) for a loop with 200K+ iterations in Python 3.6 (Anaconda 3, Windows 10 x64, PyCharm IDE). It prints the status bar too frequently, so that my earlier history disappears in the console.

Is there a way to limit the frequency of status bar updates? I can't seem to find this solution online or [tqdm website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm/4.19.5).

Currently, my status bar prints like this. Ideally, I'd like to set put a cap on percentage change. For example, update it not more frequently than once per 1% change/progress.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use *miniters* parameter i have it from source code
https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/tqdm/_tqdm.py

```
tqdm.tqdm(iterable, miniters=int(223265/100))
```

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer and the cited public API

```py
tqdm.tqdm(iterable, miniters=int(223265/100))
```

is correct but the code location has changed to here` https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/tqdm/std.py#L890-L897

Below is the description of `miniters` option:

```
miniters  : int or float, optional
    Minimum progress display update interval, in iterations.
    If 0 and `dynamic_miniters`, will automatically adjust to equal
    `mininterval` (more CPU efficient, good for tight loops).
    If > 0, will skip display of specified number of iterations.
    Tweak this and `mininterval` to get very efficient loops.
    If your progress is erratic with both fast and slow iterations
    (network, skipping items, etc) you should set miniters=1.
```

Answer (score 11):

It is convenient to use `mininterval` option that defines minimum time interval between updates. For instance, to update every `n_seconds` use:

```py
tqdm(iterable, mininterval=n_seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be seeing a different problem than the one you asked about: each update to the progress bar is written to a separate new line on your end, which has been a bug of Pycharm's for years. If you run your Python script directly in a command line, there should only be a single line showing progress, and it should keep updating. Alternatively, you can set "Emulate terminal in output console" in the run/debug configurations (see screenshot attached). However, the problem might have been fixed by an update in the meantime.

Edit: Alternatively tqdm.tqdm(iterable, position=0) might also help.

[image: Screenshot of Pycharm Run configuration]

Comment: PyCharm 2023.2.5 + tqdm 4.66.1 work fine without extra tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, `miniters` or (`mininterval` and `maxinterval`) are the way to go.

Long answer:

- Use `mininterval` and `maxinterval` (they default to 0.1 and 10 seconds respectively)
- Or, use `miniters` and `maxinterval=float("inf")` (see [#1429](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/1429) in `tqdm<=4.64.1`)
- And set `refresh=False` in calls to [`set_postfix`](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#set_postfix) and [`set_postfix_str`](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#set_postfix_str).

Three examples:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

N = 100000

# mininterval and maxinterval in seconds
for i in tqdm(range(N), total=N, mininterval=2, maxinterval=2):
    sleep(0.3)

# miniters and maxinterval=float("inf")
for i in tqdm(range(N), total=N, miniters=50, maxinterval=float("inf")):
    sleep(0.3)

# use refresh=False in set_postfix
progress_bar = tqdm(range(N), total=N, miniters=240, maxinterval=float("inf"))
for i in progress_bar:
    sleep(0.3)
    progress_bar.set_postfix({"i": i}, refresh=False)
```